# PIL & Text Draw

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have an image "testing1" that is just a plain jpeg. I have a text that is 6 sentences long. After every 2nd sentences (identified by a ".", I want the text to be drawn 100 pixels down). I was able to achieve that for the first 2 sentences, but afterwards my string concatenation includes everything before 4th period, instead of after 2nd and before 4th and not sure how to separate that. Note, I'm also using the textwrap to make sure that my sentences don't go past the width of the image.

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
import textwrap
#Open the image
font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 36)

image = Image.open("testing1.jpg")

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

texts = "We are having a long, long very long sentence here. Just trying to test if it works. We are trying to test. Testing we do all day all day. All day. Long."

image_width, image_height = image.size

y_text=600

period_count = 0 
result = ""
temp_list = [] 

for l in texts:
    temp_list.append(l)
    if l == ".": 
        period_count += 1 
        if period_count % 2==0: 
            result+="".join(temp_list)
            print(result)
            new_version = textwrap.fill(result,width = 40)
            line_width, line_height = font.getsize(l)
            draw.text(((image_width - line_width) / 2, y_text), new_version, font=font, fill=(200, 200, 200))
            y_text +=line_height+100
            temp_list = [] 
image_save("testing12.jpeg")
```

Comment: How is variable `line` defined?

Comment: @MichaelButscher I think that's just an l sorry

Comment: With `result += ...` you always add new sentences to "result" and then you draw everything in "result".

Comment: @MichaelButscher yes, I understand that that's what happening. I just don't know how to solve this.

Comment: An easy way would be to replace `result+=` by `result=` although this will change the output of the `print`.

Comment: Just add `result=""` after `temp_list=[]`, or change `result+=` to `result=`

Comment: I think this is issue is not related to PIL, but to how you split up the string and determine the subsentences. I recommend you make a helper function out of that, which makes it much more standalone and testable.